# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1918 (note 1 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1918 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries that need to be reviewed.

Here is the first one:

[image]

Initially I thought that this note was part of the larger note just below. But since 1918 is written **twice** in the left margin, and the hand writing differs, I have decided it to be a distinct note.

This is the transcribed text I came up with:

> Con fecha 8 de Abril fue destinado al puesto de la Roda de Andalucía al que se incorporó el 15 del mismo.

Are there any errors or omissions that you can see?

---

#### Translation

The above text translates as:

> On 8th April he was assigned to the post of La Roda de Andalucía, which he joined on 15th April.

I think it is clear and understandable. Agree?

---

I was also surprised by the fact that this note **does not** end with **El Comandante Mayor** or similar. This is why I originally thought this was part of the larger note.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1918 (note 2 of 2)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39495/28260)

Comment: I think that you got it completely right.

Comment: Perhaps just the accent in "incorpor**ó**"

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Thank you! I have updated the document on my PC. Shall I update the translation in the question too?

Comment: would be nice :)

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Consider it done. 