# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1918 (note 2 of 2)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1918 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are two entries that need to be reviewed.

Here is the second one:

[image]

I have tried to transcribe the text as best I can:

> Complicudo en fin de Agosto su compromiso no. 44130, solicito y le fue
> xxx por el Sr. [Señor] 1o Jefe de el Comandante nuevo xxx por cuatro
> años con xxxcion a los xxx con xxx el précite xxx hero xxx xxx xxx de
> lo que Intervención Gral. [General] de Cuerpo xxuelia en de ministra
> claudo xxx a xxx en 1o de Septiembre del año del margen y lo terminara
> en fin de Agosto de 1922 disfrutando durante el xxx el xxx diario 25
> el sitio de Herrera. Xxx huelva  de in conformidad firma la presente
> nota ante el Jefe y testigos que  xxcriben.
>
> Testigos.      El intersesado.

I can tell at the very least this this is in connection with my great-grandfather continuing in the Civil Guard for another 4 years until 1922. I have not included the signiatures in the image.

Thank you for your help in completing this transcription and translation.

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the answer provided:

> Fulfilling his commitment at the end of August no. 44130, he requested
> and was granted by Mr. 1st [First] Chief of his command a new
> reenlistment for four years with an option to the benefits granted by
> the current regulations but without prejudice to what the General
> Intervention [General] of War will definitely resolve, by beginning to
> extinguish it on September 1 of the year in the margin and will finish it
> at the end of August 1922, enjoying during the same period the daily bonus of
> 25 cents of a peseta. And in proof of his agreement, he signs this
> note before the Chief and witnesses.

I had to use Google Translate because DeepL was messing up. So I have merged the results of both translations. Let me know what you think.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1918 (note 1 of 3)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39493/28260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions

> **Cumpliendo** en fin de Agosto su compromiso no. 44130, solicitó y le fue
> **concedido** por el Sr. [Señor] 1er [Primer] Jefe de **su comandancia** nuevo **reenganche** por cuatro
> años con **opción** a los **beneficios que concede el vigente reglamento pero sin perjuicio de**
> lo que **la** Intervención Gral. [General] de **Guerra resuelva en definitiva**,  dando principio a **extinguirlo** en 1º de Septiembre del año del margen y lo terminará
> en fin de Agosto de 1922 disfrutando durante el **mismo** el **plus** diario **de** 25 **céntimos de peseta**. **Y en prueba** de **su** conformidad firma la presente
> nota ante el Jefe y testigos que **suscriben**.
>
> Testigos. El **interesado**.

We have alredy seen very similar entries for previous reenlistments.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with my translated text.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think that the translation is correct.

Comment: Great. I don't need to ask about the third note really so I will update these questions as a total of 2.